# Java GUI internal classse to separate files

Tags: java, jframe, project-management

I am writing a java program which have a big amount of different GUI objects and GUI class file became huge. I wanted to ask if there is a way to separate these internal files in different files and if so, how to do that.

The general structure of the GUI(Runner)class is following

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
 <componendt definition>

    public Gui() 
    {
        <component initialization>

        <containers and adding objects to container>

        <attaching listeners>
        // for example
        generate_button.addActionListener(new generate_ButtonHandler());
    }

    // I want to separate these classes in different files
    class generate_ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            <some suff>
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new Gui();
        f.setVisible (true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }

}
```

Or may be there is another solution how to handle these big files

Answer (score 0):

You could try implement each UI part as separate component, and encapsulate most 
code in the component. That will reduce amount of service code.